# javascript 'hex' unknown behavior

Tags: javascript, node.js

while trying to pass a hex value to the crypto cipher in node js i am getting a blank return on ciphertext while proper return on ciphertext2. Can't explain what is the difference between the two cases.

```
var secret = 'YmcNFa37DrT+0p10pnSpQSytWxlqNCyU';
var cipher  = crypto.createCipher('des3', secret);
var plaintext = '3b9ac9ff';
var ciphertext = cipher.update(plaintext, 'hex', 'hex');
var ciphertext2 = cipher.update('3b9ac9ff', 'hex', 'hex');
console.log(plaintext + ' , ' +ciphertext + ' , '+ ciphertext2);
```

gives me an output

```
3b9ac9ff ,  , 0472620ba5ddf690
```

Comment: `'hex'` is not a [valid input encoding](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_cipher_update_data_input_encoding_output_encoding): "... in `input_encoding` and can be `'utf8'`, `'ascii'` or `'binary'`"

Comment: great. thanks @Andreas  Definitely a mistake there on my part made worse by the fact that node didn't throw an error.

Comment: Is the problem solved? If so, you could add an answer and mark it as such. Just for completeness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem found. Pointed by @Andreas.

```
var ciphertext = cipher.update(plaintext, 'hex', 'hex');
```

should be

```
var ciphertext = cipher.update(plaintext, 'ascii', 'hex');
```

Two reasons which led to the confusion (although no justification for being stupid)
1. Node js doesn't give you a run time exception. Instead just behaves badly as pointed out above.
2. output is allowed as hex leading me to believe even input would be allowed.